# WebBrowser disable copy paste

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, windows-phone-7.1

I have a several question about WebBrowser control into WP7.

1. How to disable word selection by a click?
2. How to disable vertical scrollable by a gesture?

Comment: You can set IsHitTestVisible=false on the control to disable any interaction with it. Are you trying to keep some functions available? I.e. links?

Comment: @wilmel you should add that as an answer. It's not only the correct approach, it's also the recommended way of using the WebBrowser control!

Answer (score 4):

Add some extra styles to your html pages and render it on WebBrowser control

1. `body {-ms-user-select: none;}` use this css code to disable word selection by tap
    in **IE** on *Windows phone 7/8*
2. `body {-ms-touch-action: none;}`  use this css code to disable vertical scroll

   in **IE** on *windows phone 7/8*

hope this work fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

first , u can get a border control which is the container of the ie9 mobile core using visual tree helper

then

Q1: u can cancel the "Tap" gesture occurred in border control before it was passed to ie core

Q2: u can cancel the "DragDelta" gesture for some direction or distance ,well ie. vertical scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to Copy and Past = "I don't believe you can stop it from occurring, unless its your webpage and you can set it up for a Read Only Document."-If i am wrong please correct me.-

the answer to Vertical Scrollable By a Gesture = "You could build the Gesture to Return a Null instead of the event value, Pretty much tell it that if this occurs then Cancel it....Return Nothing!"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve disabling selection using javascript:

```
function DisableSelect() { var handler = function (e) {e.returnValue = false;} document.body.attachevent('onselectstart',handler,false);}
```

and than calling from your code:

```
wb.InvokeScript("DisableSelect");
```

Don't forget to detach the event.